# How to create session for sql query result in php

Tags: php, sql, session, session-variables

I want to create session for the record tag_id here is my sql code please help me how i create session for this value..

```
<?php

  $sql_tagid=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tag_new WHERE EMAIL_ID='$sessionemail' AND  CUST_ID='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
while($tagid=mysql_fetch_array($sql_tagid)){
    echo $tagid['tag_id'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to start session

```
session_start();
```

after that add variable to  session

```
$_SESSION['tag'] = $tag['tag_id']
```

after that  you can check by  print session

`print_r($_SESSION);`    you  value  in session or not

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  session_start();  // To assign a session variable you have to start the session

  $sql_tagid=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tag_new WHERE EMAIL_ID='$sessionemail' AND  CUST_ID='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

  while($tagid=mysql_fetch_array($sql_tagid))
  {

       $_SESSION['tag_id'] = $tagid['tag_id']; // assign tag_id value to session variable

       echo $tagid['tag_id'];
  }
?>
```

For getting the value of session on another page say page1.php then you have to do :-

**page1.php**

```
<?php

 session_start();

 echo $_SESSION['tag_id'];


?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rakesh Shetty i got the value of session and can i use it one that page only for insertation in another table?

Comment: yes @Yash you can,just you have to use that session variable

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['tag'] = $tagid['tag_id']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot randomizer

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you have mutliple tag id then use it `$_SESSION['tag_id'][]`, if you have only one `$_SESSION['tag_id']`

```
session_start();

while($tagid=mysql_fetch_array($sql_tagid)){
  $_SESSION['tag_id'][] = $tagid['tag_id'];
}

var_dump($_SESSION['tag_id']);
```